# Managing my users with c#, mvc on visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013

How do i modify my account controller so that it'll filter the registered people as employee or as admin or as intern for example, so that they don't all 3 see the same informations.
here is my account controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using UfpApp.Models;

namespace UfpApp.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        public AccountController()
        {
        }

        public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager )
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Login
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;

        public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            }
            private set { _signInManager = value; }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/VerifyCode
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> VerifyCode(string provider, string returnUrl, bool rememberMe)
        {
            // Require that the user has already logged in via username/password or external login
            if (!await SignInManager.HasBeenVerifiedAsync())
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(await SignInManager.GetVerifiedUserIdAsync());
            if (user != null)
            {
                var code = await UserManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user.Id, provider);
            }
            return View(new VerifyCodeViewModel { Provider = provider, ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = rememberMe });
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/VerifyCode
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> VerifyCode(VerifyCodeViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // The following code protects for brute force attacks against the two factor codes. 
            // If a user enters incorrect codes for a specified amount of time then the user account 
            // will be locked out for a specified amount of time. 
            // You can configure the account lockout settings in IdentityConfig
            var result = await SignInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync(model.Provider, model.Code, isPersistent:  model.RememberMe, rememberBrowser: model.RememberBrowser);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(model.ReturnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid code.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Register
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ConfirmEmail
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
        {
            if (userId == null || code == null)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
            return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ForgotPassword
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ForgotPassword
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
                if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
                {
                    // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                    return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
                }

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);       
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                // return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ForgotPasswordConfirmation
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ForgotPasswordConfirmation()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ResetPassword
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code)
        {
            return code == null ? View("Error") : View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ResetPassword
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                // Don't reveal that the user does not exist
                return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }
            var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ResetPasswordConfirmation
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ResetPasswordConfirmation()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
        {
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/SendCode
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SendCode(string returnUrl, bool rememberMe)
        {
            var userId = await SignInManager.GetVerifiedUserIdAsync();
            if (userId == null)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            var userFactors = await UserManager.GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync(userId);
            var factorOptions = userFactors.Select(purpose => new SelectListItem { Text = purpose, Value = purpose }).ToList();
            return View(new SendCodeViewModel { Providers = factorOptions, ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = rememberMe });
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/SendCode
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SendCode(SendCodeViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }

            // Generate the token and send it
            if (!await SignInManager.SendTwoFactorCodeAsync(model.SelectedProvider))
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("VerifyCode", new { Provider = model.SelectedProvider, ReturnUrl = model.ReturnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
            var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                    ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                    return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
                var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
                if (info == null)
                {
                    return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
                }
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/LogOff
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginFailure
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginFailure()
        {
            return View();
        }

        #region Helpers
        // Used for XSRF protection when adding external logins
        private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";

        private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            }
        }

        private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
            }
        }

        private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        internal class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
        {
            public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
                : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
            {
            }

            public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
            {
                LoginProvider = provider;
                RedirectUri = redirectUri;
                UserId = userId;
            }

            public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
            public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
            public string UserId { get; set; }

            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            {
                var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
                if (UserId != null)
                {
                    properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
                }
                context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

PS: im sorry for my english it's not my first language :/ and thanks in advance guys!

Comment: If you allow me to suggest, provide specific code to your question, otherwise seems a lot to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to learn C# you should better start with a console app and a good book. ASP.NET MVC is a framework which requires learning by itself. If you don't know C# I think it could be hard and you won't have fun learning C#.

However, you had a question I have an answer:
You can display or hide information according to the users role inside your view like this.

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
}
else if (User.IsInRole("Employee"))
{ 
}
```

In your controller you can use the Authorize Attribute to prevent access to certain actions by unauthorized users or user of another role.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public Action Result ShowAccounts()
{
}
```

You should also add an Authorize Attribute on any Controller to prevent anonymous access - like in the account controller.

```
[Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
```

Further readings:
http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-allowanonymous-attribute-and-authorize-attribute

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, hmm i really don't know wich code to provide because that's the problem, i'm learning so i really dont know wich part of the code is gonna have to be modified, really sorry :/

Comment: Thank you so much !
as for learning C# in books, i know it's the best way but it's too boring for me, i've always lerned stuff while developping makes me remember quicker and faster since i get stuck, it may seem weird to you but that's how i roll thanks again !

Comment: @ZakariaAaribi It's fine when you learn that way but you also need to focus on basics and how stuff works. I can see it in our company. It's hard to get junior engineers who know the basics. Most of them can code but don't understand it. Btw. please upvote if you found my answer helpfull.